# export slik grid data to excel using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slik

I have slikgrid to show data. I am using code like

DB return a data string separated by # then by splitting it I am creating slikgrid

```
   for (i = 0; i < DBstring.length; i++) {

        var val = DBstring[i].split('#');
        d["column1"] =val[0];
        d["colum"] = val[1];
        d["column"] = val[2];
       }
```

My grid is working fine but Now I want it to export to excel.

Please help how to do this.

PS : my code is in jquery

Comment: You could write into a .csv file which is just a list of comma separated values.

Comment: ok .csv file is still ok..but my values is # separated. How to do with # separated values